# Pronunciation of "Paraguay"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spanish

The English article for [Paraguay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraguay) in Wikipedia mentions that *Paraguay* is pronounced as [/ˈpɛərəɡweɪ/](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/En-us-Paraguay.ogg), which matches the pronunciation recommended by [Merriam-Webster](http://visual.merriam-webster.com/pronunciation.php?id=society/politics/flags/33308&title=Paraguay). However, [inogolo](http://inogolo.com/pronunciation/Paraguay) recommends [/paɾaˈɣwai/](http://inogolo.com/audio/Paraguay_3647.mp3) which is similar to the Spanish and Guarani pronunciations. I have heard both pronunciations in the U.S. but I could not find the preferred pronunciation in other places.

Although I am a native Spanish speaker, I prefer /ˈpɛərəɡweɪ/ since it seems more natural in U.S. English. This is analogous to pronouncing Florida as [/ˈflɒrɪdə/](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/En-us-Florida.ogg) instead of the Spanish-based /flo.ˈri.da/.

Does one region prefer one pronunciation over the other? Is there a pronunciation that is preferred overall?

This question also applies to the pronunciation of *Uruguay*.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Paraguay) shows that Paraguay is pronounced as /ˈpæɹ.ə.ɡwaɪ/ and /ˈpæɹ.ə.ɡweɪ/ in the UK
and /ˈpɛɹ.ə.ɡweɪ/, /ˈpæɹ.ə.ɡweɪ/, and /ˈpɛɹ.ə.ɡwaɪ/ in the US. I still want to know if there is a preferred pronunciation per region.

Comment: I pronounce it as the former,  /ˈpɛərəɡweɪ/, with Urugway "You - rue - gway" (you the word, rue the word, and gway rhyming).

Comment: I've only heard the pronunciation /ˈflɒrɪdə/ from people from New York. The rest of the U.S. says /ˈflɔrɪdə/, which is (marginally) closer to the Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to do with American English spelling and pronunciation conventions getting mixed up with foreign words and their different conventions.  The standard spelling and pronunciation of vowels in American English conflicts with Spanish spelling and pronunciation.  The a's in "paragraph" look like the ones in Paraguay, similar spelling means similar pronunciation, unless you have taken Spanish or are exposed to it.

Comment: *similar spelling means similar pronunciation* ? everywhere but in english

Comment: Maybe there are more exceptions than actual rules, but it's still a good guide when pronouncing a word you've never heard!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it answers your question, but there is a good [page](http://www.forvo.com/) where people upload the pronunciation of words in their respective languages. You can try it. Maybe you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Because "paraguay" is an indigenous name it is pronounced with the dropped "g" as "pAra we". The spelling of "Paraguay" is Spanish but the name itself is "para'we".

Comment: Where is it pronounced like this? I can find pronunciations in Spanish both with and without the /g/, but I can't tell whether that's just because some dialects of Spanish drop /g/s.

Comment: @PeterShor I travelled through Paraguay and I can attest that the /g/ is barely pronounced by locals, it's somewhere between a slight aspiration and the mildest of glottal stops. This is common throughout the Andean countries where I lived for nearly a year; *agua* (water) is pronounced the same way, more like a'wa.

Comment: @Garry, I'm not sure how you pronounce "pAra we" but the Paraguayan pronunciation roughly rhymes with the English word *eye* and a typical English pronunciation would be more like para+gw+eye.

Answer (score -2):

I invariably pronounce it /paɾaˈgwai/. It is indeed much closer to the actual Spanish pronunciation. This seems to be the standard pronunciation in Britain English in general, from my experience.

Comment: I have serious doubts that pronouncing [ɣ] is standard in any British English word.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Well it is standard (though not ubiquitous) - I'm telling you! As a Brit, I'm pretty well qualified to say so. Note that it may not be a common pronunciation for the `gu` sequence, but this is an exception since the word is Spanish in origin.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Ah, reading that again, I think you misinterpreted my use of the word 'standard'. I can see it was a bit ambiguous there. I am only talking about the words Paraguay/Uruguay. :)

Comment: If it is standard to pronounce *Paraguay* or *Uruguay* with [ɣ], I wonder why it is not listed as a UK or US variant in any dictionary.

Comment: I am British and would not pronounce any English words with [ɣ], Spanish origin notwithstanding - it gets naturalised to [ɡ], including in Paraguay and Uruguay.

Comment: Another Brit here.  This answer is nonsense; we pronounce a hard 'g' in Paraguay, similar to 'guava', or 'Gwen'.

Comment: @Jez: But that is exactly the pronunciation I am suggesting in my answer! "PARA - gw - aye", right?

Comment: No, you didn't indicate "gw", you indicated the [voiced velar fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative), a sound which doesn't exist in modern English and which is rather nasty to try and pronounce.  :-)